# String is validated as empty when it's not

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView which I use to show my feed in my social app. I am now trying to add new posts to the feed, which works fine. However, sometimes, when the added cells take up the entire screen height, the note attached to the post is not shown. This is because I have a validation which checks if the note is empty, and if it is, the subview of the note textview is removed and the constraints are changed. Take a look at the image to see what I mean (apologies for the poor quality, I was restricted to 2 MB):

[image: Missing Note]

This is where it goes wrong, in my cellForItemAt method. I have two arrays: posts and userInfo, which are filled with data correctly, because if I print all the data in cellForItemAt, it all shows as expected.

```
if let postNote = posts[indexPath.item].postNote {
    if(postNote.isEmpty) {
        socialCell.noteTextView.removeFromSuperview()
        socialCell.postDetailsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: socialCell.noteTextView.bottomAnchor).isActive = false
        socialCell.postDetailsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: socialCell.postName.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here, is decide whether the constraints should be set to the note or to the name of the post, depending on if there is a note or not. If I comment out this code, the constraints are not as they should be (obviously), but all notes are shown. So I am certain the issue can be found here: my string of the note is seen as empty, while it is not. Printing out the array or print(postNote) returns the right value.

What is happening here and how should I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Cells are re-used. When a cell that previously had an empty note is reused for a post with a non-empty note you need to ensure that the constraints are set correctly or the note will still be hidden.

Also, you don't want to keep adding constraints as the cell is re-used.  You should add the two constraints, once, in your custom cell class and then just set them to active/inactive as required.

Finally, don't remove the `noteTextView`, as again, when the cell is re-used it won't be available in the case where there is a note.  You should simply set it to `isHidden = true` or just hide it with the constraints

Something like:

```
socialCell.noteTextView.isHidden = true
socialCell.hideNoteConstraint.isActive = true
socialCell.showNoteConstraint.isActive = false

if let postNote = posts[indexPath.item].postNote, !postNote.isEmpty {
    socialCell.noteTextView.isHidden = true
    socialCell.hideNoteConstraint.isActive = false
    socialCell.showNoteConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you very much for the input. I’m sure this is the solution, as everything you say makes a lot of sense. One small question though: how should I set hideNoteConstraint and showNoteConstraint in my custom cell class (socialCell)? Should I also declare it as a global var so I can use it outside the custom class? Cheers!

Comment: Not a global, but properties of the cell class

Comment: So I’m setting showNoteConstraint and hideNoteConstraint as properties of type NSLayoutConstraint. Then, at super.init(frame: frame), I get the error Property ‘self.showNoteConstraint’ not initialized at super.init call. If I try to call them, so super.init(frame: frame, showNoteConstraint, hideNoteConstraint), I get the error Cannot invole ‘UICollectionViewCell.init’ with an argument list of type ‘(frame: CGRect, NSLayoutConstraint, NSLayoutConstraint)’.

Comment: MKe then implicitly unwrapped optionals and create them in `awakeFromNib`, or if you are using a storyboard, create them in interface builder and make them IBOutlets and connect them like any other outlet.

Comment: Because of your answer, I have tried to find a solution where I would not use constraints within the cellForItemAt method - as I read this is better not to be done there. Instead, I found a solution by using NSLayoutConstraint WithVisualFormat, where I have grouped the post items in three different views: postDetails (containing userName, postName and postNote), postStats (containing the grey elements at the bottom of each post) and the separator line. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works for now, so thank you for sending me in the right direction!